# SharePoint Client OM Tutorials?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, object-model

I'm looking for a good tutorial on how to use the SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model. All I've been able to find on the web is some snippets about getting all the list names.

I'm looking for functionality such as:

- Adding an item to a list
- Querying a list for a specific field value
- Deleting a row from a list

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using the SharePoint Foundation 2010 Managed Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx) should be helpful.

Also, I did a course for the [Pluralsight On-Demand Library](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/) on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [MSDN Video](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2010/10/12/now-available-msdn-accessing-sharepoint-2010-data-with-the-.net.aspx) by Andrew Connell